# Firebase notification via PHP just works on localhost

Tags: php, ios, firebase

I'm trying to send a Firebase Notification to an IOS app via PHP but just works on localhost

```
public function send_test(){

            $ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

            $tokens = array("<DEVICE TOKEN>", "<DEVICE TOKEN>");

            //Title of the Notification.
            $title = "Title";

            //Body of the Notification.
            $body = "Test";

            //Creating the notification array.
            $notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $body);

            //This array contains, the token and the notification. The 'to' attribute stores the token.
            $arrayToSend = array('registration_ids' => $tokens, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');

            //Generating JSON encoded string form the above array.
            $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
            //Setup headers:
            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
            $headers[] = 'Authorization: key= <API_KEY>'; // key here

            //Setup curl, add headers and post parameters.
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);       

            //Send the request
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            //Close request
            curl_close($ch);
            return $response; 

}
```

I'm using this code inside a codeigniter project .Localhost works fine and the response is:

```
{"multicast_id":5458970378798333216,"success":1,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"},{"message_id":"0:1481201473308927%dbaa52c7dbaa52c7"}]}
```

I have already added my domain on "OAuth redirect domains" list. I do not know if it helps or if there is any other configuration on Firebase console. Can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by just removing these two lines:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

and adding this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
```

Comment: That's helpful . Can we send some data with it too?